# Can I omit the subject of an adverbial clause "when..."?

Tags: dangling-modifier

In this sentence,
"*it is easy for children to bite a straw when drinking*", can I omit the subject of the adverbial clause, or I should add the subject "*they*" and "*be*", like "when they are drinking"?
I was taught that the subject of a subordinate clause can be omitted **only when** it is consistent with the subject of the main clause, otherwise it will cause **dangling structure**.

Comment: But in your example, the children *are* the "subject" of both the initial verb (explicitly) and the adverbial clause (implicitly). *It's easy for children to get bored when teaching them algebra*, on the other hand, *does* "awkwardly" switch subjects. People do say things like that, though.

Comment: TKS FumbleFingers, I thought the subject of the main clause is "it", while the subject of the adverbial clause is "children", so I'm confused

Comment: *Syntactically* speaking, the "subject" probably ***is*** "it". But that's a ***dummy*** subject - the primary *semantic* subject is initially "children" (they're the ones who easily get bored), but in my example it non-idiomatically switches to an "unspecified" subject (the implied ***you*** or ***one*** who's teaching the children). What you were taught about the subject of a subordinate clause is correct, but don't slavishly assume dummy "it" is the subject in your example. That might be true for strict grammarians who want to "assign labels", but it's irrelevant in this exact context.

Answer (score 1):

> *It is easy* [*for children to bite a straw when* [*drinking*]].

This is an extraposition construction in which the bracketed sequence is an infinitival clause functioning as extraposed subject. The grammatical subject of the whole sentence is the dummy pronoun "it".

Within the infinitival clause is the further subordinate clause, "drinking", whose understood (semantic) subject is "children". It would be possible, but not necessary, to expand this clause to  "they are drinking":

> *It is easy* [*for children to bite a straw when* [*they are drinking*]].

Here, the subject of the clause in inner brackets is "they", which has "children" as antecedent.